# How to delete the exclusions from Microsoft defender Win10?

Tags: windows-defender

I have problem deleting the following folders from the exclusions because my CPU is on `90% Usage` because of these exclusions and I don't know when and why even they are on my list. I have updated windows yesterday and my CPU starts heating up... I scanned the PC and no threat detected. But suddenly I opened the exclusion list and found some garbage is in the list which is not able to delete while the `Remove` button is disabled.
Is this a ransomware update attack or a malware attack on Microsoft server side which is providing vulnerable updates?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do 3 things to delete this.

1: Check Log files of updates and read it what happened during update.

2: Check in Registry if the above list is available in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions` and manually delete them.

3: If the above options didn't solve your Problem, I am sure your PC is hijacked. To solve it read carefully the next part.

Reset Internet Explorer and delete all addons, Delete any new internet browser/Software you have installed after updating Windows and Search for this directory in the registry:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\Microsoft\Security Center\UACDisableNotify - "1""1" -Hijack.Security.UACDisableNotify`
If you find this, Just Disconnect Internet, Boot safe Mode and delete all the threats in
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\Microsoft\Security Center\`
You will find many of them.

Comment: Run Regedit as Administrator and delete the exclusions files and folders. It is found in 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies > Microsoft > Windows Defender > Exclusions >

Comment: I just removed it from the registry as @Aman said.